# Gradle: How to publish a Android library to local repository

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library and a Android app using Gradle and Android Studio. I can include the library directly in the project as following

```
compile project(':library')
```

Because I don't want to mesh up with library source code, I want to publish the library into local repository so that I can use as

```
compile 'com.mygroup:library:1.0'
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I just found a solution. In the build.gradle of the library project, add this

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = '1.0'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://[your local maven path here]")
            // or repository(url: mavenLocal().getUrl()) 
        }
    }
}
```

In the project folder, type following command

```
gradle uploadArchives
```

Read [Publishing artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:publishing_artifacts_tutorial) for more information

Comment: `[your local maven path here]` is like `~/.m2` folder?

Comment: repository(url: mavenLocal().getUrl())

Comment: In Gradle 7.x,

The maven plugin has been removed. You should use the maven-publish plugin instead. https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#removal_of_the_legacy_maven_plugin

Answer (score 31):

For an Android Library you should use the Android Gradle-Maven plugin https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

Then to publish to your local repository run:

```
./gradlew install
```

which will install it in $HOME/.m2/repository. In your app or other project you can then include it by adding `mavenLocal()` to your repositories.

Alternatively, if your library is on GitHub then you can simply include it in other projects using [JitPack](https://jitpack.io). Then you don't have to run the above command and can just use what's been pushed.

Comment: I suppose one also needs `group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'` in the lib.

Answer (score 5):

Publish de library on your local maven repository and then on your gradle use

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

If you have other repositories listed, make sure your mavenLocal appears first.

Docs: section 51.6.4 on https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Answer (score 5):

I prefer adding the java sources and the javadoc to the maven repository. The following script publishes your android library to a maven repository using the [android maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html). It creates the .aar, javadoc.jar, sources.jar and .pom and updates the maven-metadata.xml after uploading the files to the maven repository. I also put the script on [GitHub](https://github.com/philipphofmann/android-gradle-samples/blob/master/uploadArtifactsSample.gradle).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

//Your android configuration
android {
    //...
}

//maven repository info
group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0.0'

ext {
    //Specify your maven repository url here
    repositoryUrl = 'ftp://your.maven.repository.com/maven2'
    //Or you can use 'file:\\\\C:\\Temp' or 'maven-temp' for a local maven repository
}

//Upload android library to maven with javadoc and android sources
configurations {
    deployerJars
}

//If you want to deploy to an ftp server
dependencies {
    deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ftp:2.2"
}

// custom tasks for creating source/javadoc jars
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    failOnError false
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

//Creating sources with comments
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

//Put the androidSources and javadoc to the artifacts
artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars
            repository(url: repositoryUrl) {
                //if your repository needs authentication
                authentication(userName: "username", password: "password")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with

```
./gradlew uploadArchives
```

Answer (score 2):

In `settings.gradle` add

```
include 'riz.com.mylibrary'
project(':riz.com.mylibrary').projectDir = new File('C:\\Users\\Rizwan Asif\\AndroidStudioProjects\\mylibrary')
```

Then in `build.gradle` in the dependencies add

```
compile project(':riz.com.mylibrary')
```

Comment: This the best way if you are developing a library at the same time, but I am getting an error `Configuration with name 'default' not found` when I try to grade sync.