# Android:gradle I am unable to publish aar to local repository

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am creating a library project in android studio.
Android studio implicitly supports gradle build terminologies.

I want to publish library project to local maven repository so that I can use it in other projects. (I always have option to create library in same application but I also want to distribute this library)

I took help with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361416/gradle-how-to-publish-a-android-library-to-local-repository)
With this link I am able to publish below three files

```
maven-metadata-remote.xml
maven-metadata-remote.xml.sha1
resolver-status.properties
```

**I am still not able to publish aar file to local maven repo**

***1.*** Does this has any thing to do with application's build.gradle?
 **2.** Am I missing to build aar file in library's build.gradle file?
    (though an aar file is getting built in outputs folder)

this is my library's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}

// added below code with the help of link
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.a.b'
version = '1.0'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://C:/Users/XXX User/.m2/")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you eventually find the solution?

Comment: yes, did you solve this?