# Reusing the same code across multiple Android Studio projects

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have some code I'd like to use across multiple different projects. Let's say it's some e-commerce code that handles things like payments and shopping carts.

It seems inefficient and dangerous to copy-paste everything across different projects. And if I add one feature or fix one bug in the core e-commerce module, I'd like that change to be reflected in other projects using it too.

I would also like to re-use some of the Activities, Fragments, Adapters too.

What is a good approach to this?

Comment: why dont u create your own library and use it

Comment: Create modules.

Comment: create a util project and use it as a library

Comment: you can create separate package for Activities,Fragments...and reuse them whenever you need

Answer (score 5):

When we have a library project that needs to be shared to every project on a local computer, we can make use of Maven.

A. Here the step in your library that we will you for the project:

1. Make a library project from Android Studio.
2. Add Gradle [Android Maven plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) to **root** build.gradle

   ```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
       mavenCentral()
     }

     dependencies {
       classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add apply plugin for step 1 in your library build.gradle. (NOT root build.gradle):

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
   apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
   ```
4. Add the following after the apply plugin, this line to determine your library when adding to project:

   ```
   group = 'com.yourpackage.yourlibrary'
   version = '1.0'
   ```
5. Add the following code in your settings.gradle:

   ```
   rootProject.name = 'yourlibrary'
   ```
6. Then publish it to your local maven with:

   ```
   ./gradlew install
   ```

   Or you can use gradle option in Android Studio.
7. Your library will be installed in $HOME/.m2/repository. Remember that to use the library you need to add like this:

   ```
     Groupid:artifactid:versionid
   ```

   Artifactid will be package name of your library.

**B. Here the step in your Project which using the library:**

1. Add the following code in your root build.gradle:

   ```
     mavenLocal() // for local maven.
   ```

This for getting the local library maven that we have installed in step A

2. Then in your **app** project.gradle, add compile for the library:

   ```
   compile 'com.yourpackage.yourlibrary:yourlibrary:1.0'
   ```

Read more:

- [Gradle: How to publish a Android library to local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361416/gradle-how-to-publish-a-android-library-to-local-repository)
- https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin
- https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Comment: Would this also work for bringing across UI? For example if I have a dashboard that I want to look exactly the same across multiple projects.

Answer (score -1):

From my Knowledge 1. As others said try creating your own Module or Library and use it where ever you need  2.Use Version Control Tools Like Git(If your code changes it will be refleted in your git account)