# Two projects with modules in common

Tags: android-studio

I know this has been asked before but I haven't seen a working solution.  I have two android studio (V 3.1.3) projects, MyAppBasic and MyAppPro.  They each have 3 modules in common and one that is unique.  My current implementation is duplicating the 3 common modules in each project. Obviously this is undesirable. What is the recommended way to implement these two apps and avoid code duplication?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case both of your project: MyAppBasic and MyAppPro, have almost a similar code, you can merge them and use build variant to differentiate between basic and pro app.

You also need to installing each module as a local library by using [Gradle Android Maven plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) (you can see this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33736043/4758255). Then you only need to maintain 3 common modules which is reusable as the libraries for both of your projects.

Comment: I'll check out those links later today.  Are "flavors" involved?

Comment: Yes, it's involved