# RestrictTo not restricting usage of restricted method

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-annotations

I have annotated one of my library project's method as restricted `@RestrictTo(Scope.LIBRARY)` even tried `@RestrictTo(Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)` but this not prevent the APIs from being used in the other modules of the project.
I have even tried setting `group=xxx` and `group=yyy` in both modules.

[image]

Restricting API call

[image]

No error/warning shown by the Android Studio.

[image]
Event lint is enabled for Restricted APIs.

I have even tried running lint on the caller module using `./gradlew lint`

Please find the implementation on [Github](https://github.com/UmangChamaria/TaskProcessor/tree/test/restrict_to_annotation)

library module - async-task-processor

tried setting different groups - module example

tried using a completely different package name - module myapplication

Not sure what is wrong here please help.

Comment: i am attempting to do the same thing.  I noticed that SUBCLASSES and TESTS works correctly when specifying these as RestrictTo values.  However, LIBRARY and LIBRARY_GROUP seems not to work.

Comment: @Umang have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Insightful: https://twitter.com/alexjlockwood/status/945384107424567296?lang=en

Comment: @Mr.Noob No, Haven't been able find a solution yet.

Comment: @JaredRummler I had seen the post before posting the questions, but that does not help. No lint error when calling the method as well.

Comment: @Umang I wonder if it's something to do with how the group id is defined?

Comment: Under which package is your `TaskProcessor` defined? Did you try to use a completely different package?

Comment: @Mr.Noob I have defined the group as follows **group="com.umang"**

Comment: @Antoine I have used different package names for both the projects.
Library Project's package name = **com.umang.asyncprocessor**
Caller App's package name = **com.myapplication**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From point of view `Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP` annotation all you modules is parts of one library if they have equal *groupId*

> Restrict usage to code within the same group of libraries. This corresponds to the gradle group ID.

To restrict API by `Scope.LIBRARY` you also need to use different *artifactId*

> Restrict usage to code within the same library (e.g. the same gradle group ID and artifact ID).

---

It's necessary to add library as external dependency. You need to build and deploy your library artifact:

```
// follow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28361663/3926506 to build 
artifact
group = 'com.umang.asyncprocessor'
version = '1.0'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://[path to you repository]")
            // repository(url: "file://C:/Users/Sergey/.m2/repository")
        }
    }
}
```

You can deploy artifact for example to local maven repository (don't forget to add `mavenLocal()` to project build script).

And then add dependency from **compiled library** in app build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.umang.asyncprocessor:async-task-processor:1.0'
```

not from project module:

```
// it doesn't work!
implementation project(path: ':async-task-processor')
```

I've create [pull request](https://github.com/UmangChamaria/TaskProcessor/pull/1) to your repository with appropriate configuration.

Comment: Do you mean my library should be published? Currently it is a single android studio project with 2 modules. So artifact-id and group-id does not come into picture. I wanted to test it out before releasing hence trying out this way.

Comment: @Umang I think, it doesn't matter library is published or not

Comment: In that case I am not really sure what you mean. I will push the code to github and share it. Would be great if you can have a look and help. Thanks

Comment: I have added the github url in the question please check.

Comment: @Umang I've create pull request to your repository and added notes about it to my answer, please check

Comment: The lint error shows up now, but still able to run the application with the error. If you look at some of the APIs in the support library(for example stop() in androidx.work.Worker) it shows a compilation error. Any way to achieve that??

Comment: @Umang I've checked `androidx.work.ListenableWorker.stop()` and as expected it's works the same way. How do you compile the project?

Comment: Sorry my bad it works the same way. Thanks a ton for helping out.

Comment: @Umang thanks for posting this question. Does this throw a compilation error for you now or does it only show a lint error? Thanks