# How can I set a breakpoint in an internal class of an Android library?

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, breakpoints, wallet-connect

I'm trying to help debug [Wallet Connect (v2)](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/) integration into an Android app written in Kotlin (I know Java, but am not an Android/Kotlin dev myself).

I get an exception from the [`com.walletconnect:android-core`](https://github.com/WalletConnect/WalletConnectKotlinV2/tree/develop/androidCore) library and would like to set a breakpoint (or insert some debug printing) for inspection.

Even though I would appreciate any help with Wallet Connect directly, the main purpose of this question is to figure out how I can go about debugging this myself.

The library is included in Gradle by

```
implementation("com.walletconnect:android-core:1.3.0")
implementation("com.walletconnect:sign:2.1.0")
```

The error comes from `JsonRpcInteractor` (seemlingly method `manageSubscriptions`) (no idea why they're wrapping it in `java.lang.InternalError` as it's not a JVM error):

```
java.lang.InternalError: JsonRpcInteractor: Received unknown object type
    at com.walletconnect.android.impl.json_rpc.domain.JsonRpcInteractor$handleError$1.invokeSuspend(JsonRpcInteractor.kt:271)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

In Android Studio, under External Libraries, I can only find the interface `JsonRpcInteractorInterface` that `JsonRpcInteractor` implements, but not the class itself. The class is declared as `internal class`, which I suppose might be the reason?

As I can't find the class, I also cannot set a breakpoint within it. Is there some trick that would enable me to still set a breakpoint in this class?

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31668430/883073) I also tried to replace the dependency with a local copy where I added some print statements. But in none of the variants I tried was gradle able to find the library project.

I was able to build the full `WalletConnectKotlinV2` project using `./gradlew installDebug` from the repo root (it contains other components besides `android-core`). But haven't been able to figure out exactly *where* it installs what. If only I could build the library into a `jar`, I might be able to more easily link it into the project.

Comment: Have you been able to figure out how to set a breakpoint inside an Android library? I placed a few in [SpeechRecognizer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java), where I am certain the code goes through (`mListener.onError(ERROR_CLIENT);`) but the debugger never breaks there.

Answer (score 1):

We're aware of the issue and already have [PR](https://github.com/WalletConnect/WalletConnectKotlinV2/pull/496) with a possible fix. It should be included in the next release.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).